# iOS: Difference between NSMutableArray alloc/init and arrayWithObjects:

Tags: ios, cocoa

What is the **difference** between

```
NSMutableArray* p = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:...]
```

and

```
NSMutableArray* p = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first one, you have the ownership of array object & you have to release them.

```
NSMutableArray* p = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];
[p release];
```

& last one you dont need to release as you don't have the ownership of array object.

```
NSMutableArray* p = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:...]; //this is autoreleased
```

If you call release in this, then it will crash your application.

Comment: Isn't arrayWithObjects autoreleased by default?

Comment: yes this is autorelease...we don't need to call autorelease. Thanks for editing fzwo :)

Answer (score 3):

`[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:]` is the same as `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:] autorelease]`

Comment: so, which is the better way? To alloc and release manually or to alloc with "autorelease"?

Comment: @ZhaoRocky In practice, the best way is to use ARC. If you can't use ARC, read up on manual reference counting. Neither manual retain/release nor autorelease are inherently *better*, it depends entirely on the situation.

Comment: Indeed. If one way was just "better" in all situations, the other one wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, there is no difference if you're on ARC.

The latter basically is just a shorthand for `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...]`, except the returned array is autoreleased (which is important if you're still doing manual reference counting).

Comment: Not quite. The latter autoreleases the return value.

Comment: Right. In practice, on ARC, there is no difference. Thanks for pointing that out, though. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I think the difference is that: `initWithObjects` is a instance method, and `arrayWithObject` is a class method.

Comment: While that is certainly true, it's also completely irrelevant :)